# Convergence of power series for principal branch $\arctan$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I know that the power series for the principal branch of $\arctan$ is given by $$\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$$
and it has radius of convergence 1. But I'm not sure how to deal with the case when $|x| =1$? By Abel's test, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
converges when $|x|= 1$ except possibly at 1. And I'm currently stuck here. Is there any suggestion on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\arctan(x)=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ix)^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$$since $i^{2n}=(-1)^n$. If $x=\pm i$, this series diverges (it is equal to $\mp i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2n+1}$). Otherwise, it converges, by Dirichlet's test: the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(ix)^{2n+1}$ has bounded partial sums, and the sequence $\left(\frac1{2n+1}\right)_{n\in\Bbb Z_+}$ is a monotonic sequence which converges to $0$.